# How to add an icon to a console application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, console-application

This seems like a thing that should be quite simple to do, but for some reason I have problems even to google anything on the subject...

How do you add an icon to a console application in Visual Studio. Now, I know how this works with Win32 desktop applications - you have the resource file, and the icon with the lowest ID is simply used as the app's icon. But if I add a new resource file to a console application and even mess around with the icon editor - nothing happens. The target executable still has the same default icon. Is there some kind of difference between a console application and a desktop one regarding resources? Or do I need to also do set something else apart from just adding the resource file with an icon?

Thanks

Comment: Try [this resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648051(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Creating_an_Icon) maybe

Comment: Well, I want the executable to have that icon. Things like LoadIcon can be executed at runtime but that doesn't help the executable to actually have the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the same as with normal WinAPI application. In my case the problem was probably caused by windows icons caching. You can verify this is the case by moving the executable to another directory.