# How to change the icon for a C++ basic console application?

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, console-application

I've been making a console application with C++, and I was wondering if there was a way to change stuff like the icon and application title. Also, I was wondering if it's possible to change the name of the process (I know this must be possible, since, for example, Microsoft Word is named `WINWORD.EXE`, but when I hover over the icon in the taskbar "Word 2013" shows up.).

I did some research, but they said I should look in the resource file for my program but I don't a resource file. I thought there might be something you have to do in the `main()` function like setting a variable or calling a function like `setTitle("My App")`, but I didn't find anything.

I am using Windows and the IDE [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Comment: Icons are not part of C++. I assume you're on Windows? What do you know about *resources*? Also perhaps [the Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) might have a function for setting the title.

Comment: I know, but when I make console applications with Visual Studio, the title on the window is different so I wondered if you can change it

Comment: *"Task Manager"* -- I'm going to infer from this that you are on Windows. If this is incorrect, please correct my update of your tags. (C++ has no native notion of "the icon", making this an OS-specific question.)

Comment: This question looks a lot like [How to add an icon to a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50675204), but that question seems to be a step ahead of this one (in the other question, a new resource file was added, but in this question, there is no resource file).

Comment: I figured out about the icon, I just made a `resource.rc` file and added it to the build target, the typed `2 ICON icon.ico`

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude  `SetConsoleTitle(L"My App")` worked, but when I hover over the taskbar button nothing changed